# Entropy reduction?

Tags: entropy

The following is a heuristic for the situation where a decision algorithm or a human, might solve a problem by reducing the entropy of the "search space" at every computation step $i$:

Let $X_{i+1} \subset X_i$ for $i = 1,\cdots,t-1$ be finite subsets contained all in a finite set $X_1$.

We assume that there are given functions $f_i: X_i \rightarrow X_{i+1}$ which are surjective and also we assume that $|X_{i}| > |X_{i+1}|$.
In each step $i=1,\cdots,t-1$ we might define an entropy ([the idea is borrowed from David Ellerman](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/13213/1/Logic-to-information-theory3.pdf)):

$$H_{f_i}:=H_{i} := - \sum_{x \in X_{i+1}} \frac{|f_i^{-1}(x)|}{|X_i|} \log_2\left[\frac{|f_i^{-1}(x)|}{|X_i|}\right].$$

We can also consider the function $\hat{f} = f_t \circ f_{t-1} \circ \cdots f_2 \circ f_1$ which maps from $X_1$ to $X_t$.
and consider the corresponding entropy:

$$\hat{H} = H_{\hat{f}}$$

My question is, if it can be proved that: $H_i \ge \hat{H}$ and $H_i \ge H_{i+1}$?

I did a few small [experiments in Sagemath](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJzdU8tugzAQvCPxD5ZysSmkIX0qau703AsR4kCDHbkFg2yIkr_vrjENNPmC-mDZs7O7s2OQddvojqi-bs-kMES1vldyQaT56PUX33fyyKkI03DHNr5HYFUp2ZKKK5qyARDv6ghQKfcdzXIHLsi-qdu-40SqI9eGE9ErqNYoV0Y0mpwgSFIH4DpDHUFP7IJIASCwsMnym58NZRP-2D4758uiLGeZvDL8NhWaGA5aT6NYzbteK1JUFb3qZoVacMfGOpeqg1mJ-PcWJYBEpq9phnM5Fruv0kC1y6o50D_w1DcAHGk9NzyZ9_a9wU5R0nIcwTGrov4sC3LakMMeZghLhuSFMgR0ZevgIXgKXoI4Du0R93Cd-x7EbTh4BSh4xg2DwSNua0sBEnCUyVa5e9DhGsUQFGg2qvG91L7fUZpGG6oA2E0BZCTo0e-n4HutlqqjSWKlJhKCK6gIrkh0RRfqwK1ryrAoHud1YmQ-XJ0YeRc7YKIIr1eqELxShuCg5sZvPT6wbOO5_klWiNEQOBEe3rZ2qCELcwD7ASWMFSw=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) with divisor sets, but although it seems that the answer is yes, I have no idea if it is true or how it can be proved.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Start with $X_{i+1}$  singleton. $H_i \ge 0 = H_{i+1}$ is obviously true. Then add an element to $X_{i+1}$ and have $f$ send some $y\in X_i$ to that new element. Then $H_i$ can only grow. It's a matter of showing that $\frac{a+b}{x}\log\frac{a+b}{x} \ge \frac{a}{x}\log\frac{a}{x} + \frac{b}{x}\log\frac{b}{x}$ which amounts to $(a+b)\log(a+b) \ge b\log b + c\log c$ after some obvious cancelation. This must be true. I guess you can keep going adding more elements.

Comment: @ClaudeChaunier: Thanks for your comment, but the example given in the answer below, shows that it is not true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $X_1=\{1,\dots,m+n\}$, where $m,n\to\infty$ and $\frac mn\,\log_2 n\to0$. Suppose that $f_1(x)=x$ for $x\in\{1,\dots,m\}$ and $f_1(x)=m+1$ for $x\in\{m+1,\dots,m+n\}$, so that $X_2=\{1,\dots,m+1\}$. Suppose also that $f_2(x)=x$ for $x\in\{1,\dots,m-1\}$ and $f_2(x)=m$ for $x\in\{m,m+1\}$. Then
$$H_1=\frac n{n+m}\,\log_2\frac{n+m}n
+m\frac 1{n+m}\,\log_2\frac{n+m}1\to0,$$
whereas
$$H_2=\frac2{m+1}\,\log_2\frac{m+1}2
+(m-1)\frac 1{m+1}\,\log_2\frac{m+1}1\to\infty,$$
so that $H_i\not\ge H_{i+1}$ for $i=1$.

---

However, letting $\hat f_s:=f_s\circ \cdots\circ f_1$, we of course will have
$$H_{\hat f_s}\ge H_{\hat f_{s+1}} $$
for all $s=1,2,\dots$.

This follows because $l(p):=-p\log_2 p$ (with $l(0):=0$) is concave in $p\in[0,1]$, so that $l(p+q)\le l(p)+l(q)$ if $0\le q\le1-p\le1$.

Comment: For $n=5$ don't you find $H_1 = -\frac{3}{5}\log_2\frac{1}{5} - \frac{2}{5}\log_2\frac{2}{5} = 1.92192\dots \ne \frac{1}{2}$ ?

Comment: And $H_2 = \log_2(n-1) - 1$ ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I did the calculation based on Sagemath how you described it, and I get something different, namely, that the two conjectures are true for say $n=5,7$:  https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=vskcan Maybe you used a different definition of the entropy? (I am glad, that your comment seems to be true.)

Comment: This should be fixed now.